# Rails: what is the best way to model this has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Let's say I have two models `Event` and `Person`.

Many people attend an event and a person can attend many events too.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end

create_table "events_people", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "event_id"
  t.integer "person_id"
end
```

The problem is that an event is presented by one or many `speakers`. So for a particular `event`, we should have `people` who attend that event and one or many `speakers` who are, of course, people too.

How do I do that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people
  has_and_belongs_to_many :speakers, :class_name => "Person"
end
```

And you would have an `events_speakers` join table that would match `event_id` and `person_id` (which would point to ids in your `people` table).

Comment: I haven't tried the code myself, but from how I understand the rails guide on activerecord associations, it makes sense to me that it is `speaker_id`, not `person_id` in the `events_speaker` table. This is because the HABTM association looks for a speaker.